# PostgreSQL: compare date with if else inside a procedure

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, date, stored-procedures

In a PostgreSQL procedure I was comparing 2 dates to find the lower and executes query according to it. But it shows syntax error.

Note that : **dateform** and **datestart** both are **date** type

Here is SQL:

```
IF datefrom-1 < datestart THEN
    SELECT vid
    FROM mytable.voucher
    WHERE vdate 
    BETWEEN datefrom-1 AND datestart
ELSE
    SELECT vid
    FROM mytable.voucher
    WHERE vdate 
    BETWEEN datestart AND datefrom-1
END IF;
```

But I am getting this error .

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "datefrom"
LINE 22:                IF datefrom- 1 < datestart THEN
```

I followed the official doc : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-control-structures.html

In section **39.6.2.2. IF-THEN-ELSE**

they said it should be like this :

```
IF boolean-expression THEN
    statements
ELSE
    statements
END IF;
```

I don't find any difference. Please someone point out what went wrong

Comment: Could you please show *full* procedure code and *full* error message?
The part that you show so far is missing semicolons after statements, maybe preceding fragment also has it missing.

Comment: I don't see no stinkin' javascript…